# Request another PHP file with any Method (NOT cURL!)

Tags: php, rest, request

I am building an API in PHP and want the user to include some plug-ins written in any language of choice in a designated directory. The way this should work is that the API sends a request to that user's plug-in file and returns the result.

This should be accomplished without cURL, because cURL is unavailable in this particular environment, so answers using cURL won't be helpful.

The issue that I am having is that my function literally reads the contents of the file (without executing it) when the plug-in is also written in PHP.

This is my code:

```
function sendRequest($url, $method, $body){

    $http = array(
        
        'method' => $method,
        'header' => 'Authorization: sometoken' . "\r\n".
                    'Content-Type: application/json' . "\r\n",
        'content' => $body
    
    );
    
    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => $http));

    if($file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context)){

        return $file;

    }
    else{

        return 'Error';

    }

}
```

This is an example of a simple plug-in file written in PHP:

```
<?php

    $input = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $input = json_decode($input, true);

    echo($input['a'] + $input['b']);

?>
```

When it is requested from the API it should return the value of a + b. The above code could also be implemented in any other language, it should work either way. These files are stored locally, not on a remote server (where it would work flawlessly).

Is there any way force the file to be executed without cURL? I imagine `include` and `require` are also not an option, since the plug-in file should be in a language of choice, not necessarily PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you expect the user's plugin code will be run? How do you expect to run for example python file from PHP?

Comment: What does "execute a file" mean exactly? You can execute programs. Some languages are compiled, some run through a runtime. Can you share an example of a "hello World" plugin written in PHP and one written in another random language?

Comment: The plug-in file could for example be a Node.js file that processes the request or a PHP file. A simple example would be a PHP file that just includes `<?php echo $_POST['data']; ?>`. I added another example to the question.

Comment: When `file_get_contents` is pointed at a "local file" (one residing on a path resolvable within the local filesystem), it reads the raw contents of that file. The server configured to interpret and output the result is not involved in this context. What is the value of `$url` you're passing to `sendRequest` where you're observing this behavior? You'll probably need to have it send a request to whatever server is running locally that provides the interpreter for whatever types of files you're intending to execute.

Comment: @esqew The plug-ins are stored in a directory in the local environment. That is precisely the issue. Is there any way to make it behave as if it were requesting a remote server?

Comment: @Ood As I mentioned, you'll need to fix the way you invoke `sendRequest` such that it requests the file over whatever protocol/port the target language's interpreter is bound to. Taking PHP as an example, dependent on how your server is configured, you might be able to manage calling the scripts with a URL like `http://127.0.0.1/plugins/plugin.php` - that way, the *HTTP server itself* responds with the result of the evaluation of that script (or however it's configured to respond).

Comment: @esqew I see, sorry I didn't understand it. I will give it a try and see if it works. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the examples, but they illustrate how troublesome the whole approach is. The Node example requires to open a shell process with the Node runtime, which you have to install in advance, together with the dependencies (npm packages, etc.) You'll also need to supply input data in an suitable format. The PHP one cannot be executed as shell process since it reads HTTP data directly. You need to design and set up each combination one by one. You need to carefully scope your plugin infrastructure or it'll become an operating system.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the PHP command `exec`

This would allow you do to something like:

```
exec('php plugin.php param1', $output);
```

Then read the results back via the $output variable.

Similar things could be done with other applications/scripts (provided they process with absolutely no interaction).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. This would be a solution, however, it would be limited to the languages for which there is an implementation and not any language of choice.

Comment: @ood I'm afraid if your requirements are that broad, then the answer is probably no. As far as I know, PHP cannot natively execute any non-PHP code... so you would need the server to run the command.

Comment: @Ood That's basically how Windows or Linux work. Each language you want to support needs to have a suitable compiler and/or runtime written for your platform.

Comment: I can see this approach opening severe security vulnerabilities if not implemented properly. With the right conditions upstream from this code, it would be pretty easy to get this type of setup to execute arbitrary commands. `exec('php plugin.php; cat /etc/passwd; #param1', $output)`

Comment: @esqew That is true. Only reviewed plug-ins would be used so that would avoid the issue.